# $index - Do not reset

Tags: angularjs

I have an array that looks something like the following:

```
[
    {
       make: 'Ferrari',
       cars: [{n: '458', y:'2012'}, {n: 'F40', y: '1987'}]
    },
       make: 'Lamborghini',
       cars: [{n: 'Countach', y: '1980'}, {n: 'Diablo', y: '1995'}]
    }
]
```

I display the list like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="m in carMakeList">
    <span>{{m.make}}</span>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="c in m.cars" 
            ng-click="selectItem(c)"
            ng-class="{'highlight':(selectedIndex===$index)}">
            {{c.n}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What I want is, the **$index** to **CONTINUE**, and **NOT** **reset** between the 2 **inner** `car` lists.

So the list should be like the following:

```
$index=0 -> 458
$index=1 -> F40
$index=2 -> Countach
$index=3 -> Diablo
```

How do I do this?

I've tried using ng-init to set an index value and increment it manually, but it doesn't seem to work. It seems to always reset.

Comment: you could separate out all the `cars` object in one single array using filter & do use `ng-repeat` on it

Comment: Check your object paranthesis. Second object is not wrapped.

Answer (score 0):

`$index` is a *special* scope property that keeps track of the index of an object in a collection being iterated over. You should not overload that property, but rather use your own scope property, or a custom function to look up the flattened index. The following is an example of a custom index lookup function:

```
$scope.carMakeList = [
    {
       make: 'Ferrari',
       cars: [{n: '458', y:'2012'}, {n: 'F40', y: '1987'}]
    }, {
       make: 'Lamborghini',
       cars: [{n: 'Countach', y: '1980'}, {n: 'Diablo', y: '1995'}]
    }
];
$scope.flattenedIndex = function(car) {
  var currentIndex = -1;
  var actualIndex = -1;
  $scope.carMakeList.forEach(function(eachBrand) {
    eachBrand.cars.forEach(eachCar) {
      currentIndex += 1;
      if (car === eachCar) {
        actualIndex = currentIndex;
      }
    }
  });
  return actualIndex;
}
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="m in carMakeList">
  <span>{{m.make}}</span>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="c in m.cars" ng-click="selectItem(c)" ng-class="{'highlight':(selectedIndex===flattenedIndex(c))}">
      {{c.n}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a different take on issue.

I actually solved your problem in a different way instead of solving $index. I used track by for unique identifier which is `c.n` here.
Track is much more efficient than your $index because $index is a serious load specially when you are using two Ng-repeats.

Do give your feedback.

Find the code plus fiddle below.

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
<div ng-repeat="m in carMakeList">
    <span>{{m.make}}</span>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="c in m.cars track by c.n" 
            ng-click="selectItem(c.n)"
            ng-class="{'highlight':(selectedIndex===c.n)}">
            {{c.n}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
 var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);
    myApp.controller("myController",function($scope){
      $scope.actualIndex;
        $scope.selectItem = function(actualIndex){
        $scope.selectedIndex = actualIndex;
        };
    $scope.carMakeList = [
        {
           make: 'Ferrari',
           cars: [{n: '458', y:'2012'}, {n: 'F40', y: '1987'}]
        },
        {  make: 'Lamborghini',
           cars: [{n: 'Countach', y: '1980'}, {n: 'Diablo', y: '1995'}]
        }
    ];

    });
```

**CSS**

```
.highlight {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/3r14kq1x/